# Whats wrong with this nested query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query to return the id of the latest version of a market index stored in a database.

```
SELECT miv.market_index_id market_index_id from ref_market_index_version miv 
INNER JOIN ref_market_index mi ON miv.market_index_id = mi.id 
WHERE mi.short_name='dow30' 
AND miv.version_num = (SELECT MAX(m1.version_num) FROM ref_market_index_version m1 INNER JOIN ref_market_index m2 ON m1.market_index_id = m2.id )
```

The above SQL statement can be (roughly) translated into the form:

```
SELECT some columns FROM SOME CRITERIA MATCHED TABLES 
WHERE mi.short_name='some name'
AND miv.version_num = SOME NUMBER
```

What I don't understand is that when I supply an actual number (instead of a sub query), the SQL statement works - also, when I test the SUB query used to determine the latest version number, that also works - however, when I attempt to use the result returned by sub query in the outer (parent?) query, it returns 0 rows - what am I doing wrong here?

Incidentally, I also tried an `IN CLAUSE` instead of the strict equality match i.e.

```
... AND miv.version_num IN (SUB QUERY)
```

That also resulted in 0 rows, although as before, when running the parent query with a hard coded version number, I get 1 row returned (as expected).

BTW I am using postgeresql, but I prefer the solution to be db agnostic.

Comment: Have u tried giving an alias to the subquery?

Comment: How can `market_index_id` be both the foreign key to `ref_market_index` and the id of the version record you're looking for?  Won't it always be the value of `ref_market_index.id` for the matching record?  Also, your subquery doesn't have any relation to the main table, so how is it finding the maximum version number relevant to the record `mi.id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that the max(version_num) doesn't exist for 'dow30'.

Try the following correlated subquery:

```
SELECT miv.market_index_id market_index_id
from ref_market_index_version miv  INNER JOIN
     ref_market_index mi
     ON miv.market_index_id = mi.id 
WHERE mi.short_name='dow30' AND
      miv.version_num = (SELECT MAX(m1.version_num)
                         FROM ref_market_index_version m1 INNER JOIN
                              ref_market_index m2
                              ON m1.market_index_id = m2.id
                         where m1.short_name = 'dow30'
                        )
```

I added the where clause in the subquery.

Comment: I think you didnt catch the point here, he isnt trying to filter out the subquery by 'dow30' just the outer query

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  The max(version_num) in the subquery is the max over all mi.short_name.  Clearly, the overall max in the data is different from the max for 'dow30'.  S/he needs to get the max for the index selected by the outer query.

Comment: Then how do you explain that when he runs the subquery by itself it returns the expected value?

Comment: Only the original questioner can determine whether my answer helps.  I would explain it your question, though, by saying that s/he tested the subquery to see if it returned a value (which it does) but not if it returned the right value for dow30.